# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException offset(23) is out of bounds [0, 0] JetPack Compose OutlinedTextField

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Facing one crash in the jetpack compose, can anyone please help me with this.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: offset(23) is out of bounds [0, 0]
   at androidx.compose.ui.text.MultiParagraph.requireIndexInRangeInclusiveEnd(MultiParagraph.kt:593)
   at androidx.compose.ui.text.MultiParagraph.getBidiRunDirection(MultiParagraph.kt:406)
   at androidx.compose.ui.text.TextLayoutResult.getBidiRunDirection(TextLayoutResult.kt:353)
   at androidx.compose.foundation.text.CoreTextFieldKt.SelectionToolbarAndHandles(CoreTextField.kt:816)
   at androidx.compose.foundation.text.CoreTextFieldKt.access$SelectionToolbarAndHandles(CoreTextField.kt:1)
   at androidx.compose.foundation.text.CoreTextFieldKt$CoreTextField$4$1$1.invoke(CoreTextField.kt:565)
   at androidx.compose.foundation.text.CoreTextFieldKt$CoreTextField$4$1$1.invoke(CoreTextField.kt:527)
   at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
   at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
   at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposablesKt.ReusableComposeNode(ComposablesKt.java:443)
   at androidx.compose.foundation.text.selection.SimpleLayoutKt.SimpleLayout(SimpleLayout.kt:79)
   at androidx.compose.foundation.text.CoreTextFieldKt$CoreTextField$4$1.invoke(CoreTextField.kt:527)
   at androidx.compose.foundation.text.CoreTextFieldKt$CoreTextField$4$1.invoke(CoreTextField.kt:510)
   at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
   at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
   at androidx.compose.material.OutlinedTextFieldKt.IconsWithTextFieldLayout-T2E5_Oc(OutlinedTextField.kt:452)
   at androidx.compose.material.OutlinedTextFieldKt.access$OutlinedTextField$lambda-3(OutlinedTextField.kt:1)
   at androidx.compose.material.OutlinedTextFieldKt$OutlinedTextFieldLayout$1.invoke(OutlinedTextField.kt:350)
   at androidx.compose.material.OutlinedTextFieldKt$OutlinedTextFieldLayout$1.invoke(OutlinedTextField.kt:348)
   at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
   at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
   at androidx.compose.foundation.text.CoreTextFieldKt.CoreTextField(CoreTextField.kt:510)
   at androidx.compose.foundation.text.BasicTextFieldKt.BasicTextField(BasicTextField.kt:262)
   at androidx.compose.material.OutlinedTextFieldKt.OutlinedTextFieldLayout-uBqXD2s(OutlinedTextField.kt:322)
   at androidx.compose.material.TextFieldImplKt$TextFieldImpl$3.invoke-h1eT-Ww(TextFieldImpl.kt:207)
   at androidx.compose.material.TextFieldImplKt$TextFieldImpl$3.invoke(TextFieldImpl.kt:129)
   at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:214)
   at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
   at androidx.compose.material.TextFieldTransitionScope.Transition-DTcfvLk(TextFieldImpl.kt:357)
   at androidx.compose.material.TextFieldImplKt.TextFieldImpl(TextFieldImpl.kt:119)
   at androidx.compose.material.OutlinedTextFieldKt.OutlinedTextField(OutlinedTextField.kt:270)
   at androidx.compose.material.OutlinedTextFieldKt.OutlinedTextField(OutlinedTextField.kt:157)
   at com.zee5.presentation.search.searchrefinement.composable.SearchRefinementScreenKt.TopTextInputView(SearchRefinementScreen.kt:131)
   at com.zee5.presentation.search.searchrefinement.composable.SearchRefinementScreenKt.SearchRefinementScreen(SearchRefinementScreen.kt:74)
   at com.zee5.presentation.search.searchrefinement.fragment.SearchRefinementFragment$onCreateView$1$1.invoke(SearchRefinementFragment.kt:60)
   at com.zee5.presentation.search.searchrefinement.fragment.SearchRefinementFragment$onCreateView$1$1.invoke(SearchRefinementFragment.kt:56)
   at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
   at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
   at androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl.compose(RecomposeScopeImpl.kt:140)
   at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recomposeToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2158)
   at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.skipCurrentGroup(Composer.kt:2404)
   at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2585)
   at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2571)
   at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:247)
   at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(SnapshotStateKt.java:1)
   at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:2571)
   at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recompose$runtime_release(Composer.kt:2547)
   at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.recompose(Composition.kt:620)
   at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:786)
   at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.access$setCloseCause$p(Recomposer.kt:105)
   at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:456)
   at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:425)
   at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiFrameClock$withFrameNanos$2$callback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiFrameClock.android.kt:34)
   at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:109)
   at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$setScheduledFrameDispatch$p(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
   at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:69)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:947)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:693)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6953)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:590)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Do you have a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? First thought is that you're zeroing the text without reseting selection range

Comment: No its not reproducible, its firebase crash report.

Comment: I found [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/188681404) on the internet. We have 3 crash reports on TextField which use visual transformation with Compose 1.1.1

Answer (score 3):

We receive these crash logs regularly with Compose 1.1.1 and TextField using visual transformation. The problem was a dynamic change of visual transformation from `VisualTransformation.None` to our custom one after the user long pressed on input with some value inside it. And because we change that in `onFocusEvent` if `FocusState.isFocused == true` then race condition occurred somewhere in the `TextField`.

Our solution was to change visual transformation also on initial value change using `value` key inside `remember` statement

```kotlin
val ourCustomTransformation = remember {
    OurCustomTransformation()
}

var visualTransformation by remember(value) {
    mutableStateOf(
        if (value.isBlank()) {
            VisualTransformation.None
        } else {
            ourCustomTransformation
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: My keyboard type is number ...if i enter . (dot)(say special character).. app is crashing getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: offset(1) is out of bounds [0, 0] compose

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not a problem with Firebase, but a problem with displaying your data, in particular with the offset mapping. Do you use some kind of visual transformation?
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/input/VisualTransformation

(I'd like rather to put this in the comments, but I'm not allowed to comment yet)