# App crashes when trying to use VisualTransformation in a TextField

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

So i'm trying to implement the top answer in this thread

[StackOverflow demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71274129/phone-number-visual-transformation-in-jetpack-compose)

as well as follow along with the following video

[YouTube demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s33jZeGAhdQ)

The app builds fine, but as soon as I click the TextField to begin inserting data the app crashes with the following error (the stack trace is far too big to copy in I think)

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: OffsetMapping.transformedToOriginal returned invalid mapping: 12 -> 10 is not in range of original text [0, 0]
```

I simply cannot see where the issue lies as there is basically no deviation from the examples given apart from small alterations to the mask and offset to suit the format I am going for. But as far as I can see these should be ok. My code sample is as follows.

```
    @Composable
fun DisplayPhoneNumberTextField() {

    var mobileNo by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    OutlinedTextField(
        value = mobileNo,
        onValueChange = { mobileNo = it},
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        placeholder = {
            Text(text = "Phone Number")
        },
        singleLine = true,
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
            focusedIndicatorColor = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary
        ),
        visualTransformation = {
            phoneNumberInputFormatter(it)
        },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
    )
}


private fun phoneNumberInputFormatter(text : AnnotatedString) : TransformedText {

    val mask = "xxx-xxx-xxxx"

    val trimmed = if(text.text.length >= 10) text.text.substring(0..9) else text.text

    val annotatedString = AnnotatedString.Builder().run {
        for (i in trimmed.indices){
            append(trimmed[i])
            if (i == 2 || i == 5){
                append("-")
            }
        }
        pushStyle(SpanStyle(color = Color.LightGray))
        append(mask.takeLast(mask.length - length))
        toAnnotatedString()
    }

    val phoneNumberOffsetTranslator = object : OffsetMapping {
        override fun originalToTransformed(offset: Int): Int {
            if (offset <= 2) return offset
            if (offset <= 5) return offset + 1
            if (offset <= 9) return offset + 2
            return 12
        }

        override fun transformedToOriginal(offset: Int): Int {
            if (offset <= 2) return offset
            if (offset <= 5) return offset - 1
            if (offset <= 9) return offset - 2
            return 10
        }
    }

    return TransformedText(annotatedString, phoneNumberOffsetTranslator)

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: The crash is a result of this line: append(mask.takeLast(mask.length - length)). I haven't debugged why but the quick fix is to remove the mask being appended

Comment: You may also have issues with your OffsetMapping. See this example for more info https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/input/VisualTransformation

Answer (score 1):

@murphler, I could be wrong here, but I think your mask variable is getting added to the total length which is why it's offset it crashing. Try making `mask = ""` and see if that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like possible duplicate of this: [Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException offset(23) is out of bounds [0, 0] JetPack Compose OutlinedTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71464420/fatal-exception-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-offset23-is-out-of-bounds)
i.e., input is empty when mapping is done

Maybe you can try returning `TransformedText` like this instead of custom transformation:

```
return TransformedText(annotatedString, OffsetMapping.Identity)
```

Or, you can try solutions provided in above like i.e., return `OffsetMapping.Identity` when input is empty and `customMapping` when there is input

Comment: if you think it's a duplicate, then why did you flag it as one?